# Rumble strip noise on 1999 F250

Tags: wheels

I have the "sounds like driving on a rumble strip when I hit a bump" problem. I've read through the many threads about it on other sites and I'm trying to narrow down the cause for mine. There are many, many suggested causes and no one seems to come back to declare what it actually was.

I got under the truck to try to check for play in the front end assemblies and found something weird. It's a seal between the front, passenger side wheel knuckle and the hub and it's just hanging loose. Also when I push on the knuckle, there is a lot of play. Here is a video that can show this better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGsCZ8gluJI

Another important thing: I just had the front wheel hub assemblies replaced 3k miles ago. Here's a copy of my receipt for the work: http://magnatecha.com/_media/20160412010058.png

Anyone have any thoughts on how to describe and fix the seal issue and if it could be causing the noise when I hit a bump?

Info about my truck:

```
1999 Ford F250
extended cab
5 spd manual transmission
Gas V10
4x4
```

Additional notes:

- Acceleration and breaking do not cause or stop it
- The pitch of the noise changes as I slow down
- If I stop completely, the noise does not occur when I start moving again

Comment: How's the clearance between the tires and wheel wells?

Comment: @Zaid there's a lot of clearance: http://magnatecha.com/_media/20160412014306.png

Comment: Ha, I thought this was a dupe when I started reading..  [This guy](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/28138/12030) is also having a "sounds like a rumble strip" problem, but it seems unrelated...

Comment: try tightening the wheel nut on the passenger side first thats a lot of play in that u joint.

Comment: @Ben,  the wheel lug nuts? I've gone around the truck and tried them all. They were all tight.

Comment: there should be a nut in the center of the hub that holds the ujoint/axle to the hub watching the video it looks like its loose

Comment: it should be torqued to at least 188 ft lbs

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there another name for it? I want to look up how to do it, but searching for "wheel nut" returns items assuming I mean lug nuts that hold the wheel on.

Comment: Looking at this page, I do not see a nut inside the hub: frontiernet.net/~jmray/F250BallJoints.htm

Answer (score 1):

See if your shock is still in  a good condition. Push or jump on each side of the vehicle whichever way you can do it and see how long it takes for car to stop moving. Good shocks would stop the movement in one 1.5 compressions. Bad shocks 2 or more.

Might be the wheel bouncing because of bad shock and with that all other issues with your suspension getting destroyed because of un-absorbed energy.

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say it but the seal is bad and needs replaced.  From video looks like it was not replaced 3K ago (should have been part of hub service).
When hub was replaced the outer driven shaft retainer was not proper installed or not installed (or some thing related to that). This is cause for the excessive play on that shaft and hence the noise.  Does that wheel drive proper in 4 wheel drive?